# Передача данных из хранилища в вычисляемое свойство

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Возникла проблема с выводом данных из JSON в компонент. Есть компонент filter.vue, который получает через axios внешний JSON и фильтрует данные из него:

```
<template> 
   <section>
    <div v-for="mathId in mathIds">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedMathIds" v-bind:value="mathId" /> {{mathId}}
    </div>
    <div v-for="job in filteredMathes">
      <h2>{{ job.id }}) {{ job.title }}</h2>   
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: "FilterMatches",
  data() {
    return {     
      mathes: [],
      mathIds: [1,2,3],
      checkedMathIds: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get('/js/mydata.json')
      .then(response => (this.mathes = response.data))
  },  
  computed: {
    filteredMathes() {
      if (!this.checkedMathIds.length)
        return this.mathes
      return this.mathes.filter(job => this.checkedMathIds.includes(job.mathId))
    }

  },

};
</script>
```

Компонент работает, как надо. Также есть VueX-хранилище games.js

```
//VueX store
export default {

 state: {
    games: {         
    },
  },

  getters: {
    games: state => state.games
  }, 

  actions: {          
    loadGameData({commit}) {
      axios.get('/js/mydata.json').then((response) =>      {       
        commit('getGame', response.data)  
      });   

    },
  },
     mutations: {
    getGame(state, games) {
      state.games = games;      
    },
  }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы filter.vue получал JSON не через axios внутри created(), а из хранилища games.js? Я знаю, что внутри компонента можно диспатчить экшен loadGameData таким образом:

```
created() {    
     this.$store.dispatch('loadGameData');
  },
```

Но что делать дальше? Как передать эти данные в вычисляемое свойство filteredMathes() ?
Дополнено: согласно ТЗ, фильтрация должна быть осуществлена именно внутри компонента, а не в хранилище.

Comment: Ну так из компонента обратитесь в стор

Comment: Если бы я понимала, как именно это сделать, то не задавала бы вопрос.

Comment: Если я правильно поняла, в вашем примере фильтрация происходит в сторе. Есть ли способ все-таки осуществить фильтрацию непосредственно в компоненте? Таково требование ТЗ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так замените computed свойство в компоненте, если нужно еще фильтровать, то настройте фильтр в сторе или уже в самом методе компонента

```
computed: {
  filteredMathes() {
    const games = this.$store.getters.games
    return games.filter(job => this.checkedMathIds.includes(job.mathId))
  }
}
```

Comment: Извините, я не поняла. Нужно перенести фильтр из вычисляемого свойства в метод? А как его тогда потом вызвать в темплейте? Простите, я довольно плохо знаю Vue и мне сложно сориентироваться без конкретных примеров кода. Чтение документации мне не помогло...

Comment: Нет, я просто предложил, если нужно уже фильтрованное, то можно вынести фильтр в стор.

Comment: По сути у вас уже все есть, я подправил выше код. Вы должны понять нет разницы откуда вы получили данные их стора или запросом, работает с ними вы также.